# Access list element based on attribute value

Tags: r, list, attributes

Say I have a list whose elements have attributes, as below:

```
my_list <- list()

my_list[[1]] <- 1:10
my_list[[2]] <- 11:20
my_list[[3]] <- 21:30

attr(my_list[[1]], "att1") <- "a"
attr(my_list[[2]], "att1") <- "b"
attr(my_list[[3]], "att1") <- "c"

attr(my_list[[1]], "att2") <- "1"
attr(my_list[[2]], "att2") <- "2"
attr(my_list[[3]], "att2") <- "3"
```

Now, pretend this list is many hundreds of elements long, and I don't know a priori which element of the list has the attributes I want. But I know that I want the element, with say, att1 == "b" and att2 == "2" (but where I don't know that it happens to correspond to list element 2).

Is there a way in R to look up which element(s) in a list has a particular combination of attributes?

Comment: `Filter(function(x) attr(x, "att1") == "b" & attr(x, "att2") == "2", my_list)`? Or maybe `sapply` if you want to know true/false for each element... Btw, if you put this in a table, lookup will be easier.

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed do the trick! The package I'm using returns a mess of cross-validation matrices as list elements with attributes corresponding to tuning parameters -- hence why I'm looking for how to look up list elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter a list with `Filter`:

```
Filter(function(x) attr(x, "att1") == "b" & attr(x, "att2") == "2", my_list)
```

If you expect the element to be unique and want to select it, add `[[1]]` on the end.

---

Personally, I'd put the data into a table:

```
library(data.table)
myDT = data.table(
  att1 = sapply(my_list, attr, "att1"), 
  att2 = sapply(my_list, attr, "att2"),
  data = my_list
)

#    att1 att2               data
# 1:    a    1       1,2,3,4,5,6,
# 2:    b    2 11,12,13,14,15,16,
# 3:    c    3 21,22,23,24,25,26,
```

Then you can verify that att1 + att2 uniquely pin down an element

```
nrow(myDT) == uniqueN(myDT, by=c("att1", "att2"))
# [1] TRUE
```

and write a helper function for subsetting

```
setkey(myDT, att1, att2)
get_element = function(a1, a2) myDT[.(a1, a2), data[[1]]]

get_element("b", "2")
#  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# attr(,"att1")
# [1] "b"
# attr(,"att2")
# [1] "2"
```

You might also want to look at the purrr and broom packages, which offer different, "tidyverse" syntax for tables with a list column.

Answer (score 4):

A good solution (with clear logic behind answer) has already been provided by @Frank. Still I thought to cover couple of other options (again, already hinted by @Frank in his answer).

**Option#1:**

```
library(purrr)
my_list %>% keep(~ attr(., "att1") == "b" & attr(., "att2") == "2")

#[[1]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#attr(,"att1")
#[1] "b"
#attr(,"att2")
#[1] "2"
```

**Option#2:** Using `sapply`

```
my_list[sapply(my_list, function(x)attr(x, "att1") == "b" & attr(x, "att2") == "2")]
# [[1]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# attr(,"att1")
# [1] "b"
# attr(,"att2")
# [1] "2"
```

Comment: Dunno why this got a downvote. Seems like a good illustration of how to use purrr for this (I didn't know how).

Comment: Thanks @Frank! That's surprising to me as well. I thought to complete various options after considering your hint. But was surprised to have down-vote, which prompted me to recheck answer. May be some random users:-)

Comment: I upvoted! I am fairly unfamiliar with purrr, so I thought this was super useful!

Answer (score 3):

May be this:

```
ls_attr <- sapply(my_list, attributes)
ls_attr
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# att1 "a"  "b"  "c" 
# att2 "1"  "2"  "3"

my_list[ apply(ls_attr, 2, function(x) all( x %in% c('b', '2') )) ]
# [[1]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
# attr(,"att1")
# [1] "b"
# attr(,"att2")
# [1] "2"
```

Another solution with multiple attributes: No constraints on the order of attributes with this code.

```
ls_attr <- sapply(my_list, attributes)
search_attr <- matrix( c( 'c', 'b', 2:3), ncol = nrow(ls_attr), byrow = TRUE )
my_list [ apply( matrix( ls_attr %in% search_attr, nrow = nrow(ls_attr), byrow = FALSE ), 2, all) ]
```

Comment: Why not just `my_list[colSums(ls_attr == "b" | ls_attr == "2") == 2]` instead of the `apply` loop?

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks for the comment. Many ways to approach it. I tried not to loop through the list, but to extract the attributes first, and finally used the data (my_list) to extract the contents